# Adding a Google +1 button in Android App

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

I was just wondering if there was anyway to add a Google +1 button inside my Android app.
I have seen a +1 on the Android Market so I would think there would be some way to do this.

Comment: hey guys I have generated client id for +1 button but don't know where to use in code . any idea ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With the Google+ platform for Android, you are now able to integrate a native +1 button in your Android app.

1) You first need to [initialize](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#initialize_the_plusclient) the `PlusClient` object in your Activity.

2) Include the PlusOneButton in your layout:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        plus:size="standard"
        plus:annotation="inline" />
```

3) Assign the PlusOneButton to a member variable in your Activity.onCreate handler.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this);
    mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
}
```

4) Refresh the PlusOneButton's state each time the activity receives focus in your Activity.onResume handler.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
    mPlusOneButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL);
}
```

For more information, see https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#recommend_content_with_the_1_button

Comment: You should remove the Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE according to the last update

Comment: The PlusClient Constructor is no longer supported, you should use the PlusClient.Builder$build

Comment: what is the URL variable?

Comment: @CuongThai that is the actual URL that you want the user to add +1

Comment: In my case, I put the link to the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package.app

Comment: Kirill Kulakov: can you edit the code or give a correct answer with PlusClient.Builder ? I have the error explained in the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713451/google-plus-android-api-the-method-setactionsstring-is-undefined-for-the-t#  when using PlusClient.Builder or when trying to run the Google+ sample app by Google. Thanks for your help !

Comment: There is no method in PlusOneButton which takes (PlusClient,URL) as arguments. Also, is a PlusClient really required now? It worked for me without the PlusClient for 2-3 weeks for me until all of a sudden it stopped working. The button is always frozen for no reason.

Comment: The button is frozen because with the new update of google play services library, you can only +1 when the user is signed in.The previous library was better as it signed in the user when clicking +1 button but with the new one you have to first sign in the user then the google plus button will be activated. Fellow googlers told me they are working on the fix but we still dont know when the update will be ready.

Comment: This answer is outdated. mPlusClient is no longer required and anyways mPlusOneButton.initialize() won't take it. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) for new approach

Answer (score 10):

the accepted answer is outdated....

XML :

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
  xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
  android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  plus:size="standard"
  plus:annotation="inline" />
```

Activity :

```
// The request code must be 0 or greater.

    private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
    mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and even before that fallow this link  :

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Comment: What does the PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE used for?

Answer (score 1):

With new android studio(2.2.2 that's what i'm using) you can do it more easily.
There is built in feature to create fragment with +1 button. You can use the layout or initialization code for PlusOneButton in an activity or anywhere you want.
Check the following image: [image]

Edit: Don't forget to configure your app in Google api console