# Google +1 button in android

Tags: java, android, debugging, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a Google +1 button in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app)

Is there any API for putting a +1 button in android? if there's not, how to implement that?

Comment: but there isn't given any way to implement.

Comment: Would a javascript/html android app allow this?  Similar to PhoneGap or something else?

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari the answer in the post says there is a HTML/JavaScript way only for this. You can start  your search afresh, now that you know there is no API for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIk, Google has given JavaScript for it. Look : http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/ for details and customise JavaScript for your need