# Implement google plus button in android app

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Is it possible to add a google plus button added to my android app and have it linked to the one that one that is displayed at the top of the google play store , below the app name? So that when people click the button in the app, the count on the play store would go up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Google +1 button in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app)

Comment: This IS NOT A DUPLICATE, I want to link Mine to the opne in the play store, while he/she just wants to add one to thier app. I read that one before i posted it did not help my situation

Answer (score 2):

According to the G+ docs, a +1 button is associated with a particular URL. So, if you can figure out what URL the +1 button in Google Play is associated to, then you should be able to construct a G+ button following the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app) (that I know you've already seen) with that URL and you should be all set. My best guess is that it's the play store URL associated with your app...http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package

Sounds like you also want the user to end up in Google Play after they click? If so, just follow the directions [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) - perhaps you could subclass `PlusOneButton` or set some click handler on it (calling `super`) to allow the whole G+ functionality to work before navigating them to the Play Store.