# how to add a G+ follow in android application

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to add a "follow us on G+" button in an android app to follow my page, it is avaliable in web 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/

i want to do the same but in my Android app, is there any thing like the +1 button

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        plus:annotation="inline"
        plus:size="standard" />
```

but for G+ follow?
thanks for helping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app Seems like this is what you want to do?

Comment: no actually i have done this, but what i want is G+ follow Button not +1 like button

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that provided by the plus client for android. You can try using a WebView and loading the JavaScript button that they provide for the web API.