# Google Plus Android API: "The method setActions(String[]) is undefined for the type PlusClient.Builder"

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to make the sample Android Google+ app working... (sample app provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android )

I am getting a compiling error on the "setAction" methods:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions(MomentUtil.ACTIONS) // Compiling error here !
                .build();
```

I get "The method setActions(String[]) is undefined for the type   PlusClient.Builder"

Anybody knows why I get this error ???

Thanks !!

Comment: Which version of Google Play Services do you have installed?

Comment: Ok, there was indeed a problem of version. Now, I have: 1) on my phone: Services Google Play version 3.2.66 2) On my Mac: SDK rev. 13   Now, I can launch the Google Plus SDK sample app but when I want to sign in this sample app I have got the message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services"... Any idea on the reason of this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to SDK Manager and go to extras and select google play services and install latest update.

2) Then browse through your sdk folder like sdk/extras/google/.. You will find the library project.Import that project into workspace and add it as library to ur project.

3) Then clean build and run.

Answer (score 1):

> "The method setActions(String[]) is undefined for the type
>   PlusClient.Builder"

means you are passing String array to setActions method but as in API Doc [setActions (String... actions)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.Builder.html#setActions%28java.lang.String...%29) method takes `String` as action parameters instead of String Array

because `setActions` method takes variable arguments([Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html))  so you can pass multiple sting in setActions method without using array as:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions(MomentUtil.ACTIONS[0],
                            MomentUtil.ACTIONS[1],....) 
                .build();
```

Comment: Do you mean that I have to correct the code of the Google sample app which would be wrong ? There are many places in the code where this error occurs and it is not so easy to correct it in all cases... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, there was a problem of version. Now, I have: 1) on my phone: Services Google Play version 3.2.66 2) On my Mac: SDK rev. 13.  Now, I can launch the Google Plus SDK sample app but when I want to sign in this sample app I have got the message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services"... Any idea on the reason of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

They changed the method name from setActivities to setActions.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.Builder.html