# How to use api key while working with GooglePlus api

Tags: android, google-plus

Im learning the way to have google plus sign in the android app. I have followed the steps mentoined in [https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started), and generated an api-key, and downloaded the sample application in the developer site. But now I don't have the place to give the generated api-key, everytime I run the app, I get following error:

I/GLSUser(3628): GLS error: INVALID_CLIENT_ID abc.cdef@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

Can anyone tell me the way to give the api key in the app, apologies if this is a duplicate post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Google +1 button in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app)

Comment: Thanks for the post, helps me a lot.